# Extract bibliographic references from pdf files to a bib file

Tags: bibliographies, pdf

Is there a software which can parse pdfs and extract  bibliographic references? ACM DL is a web service which can give that info like here: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=296806.296823&coll=ACM&dl=ACM&CFID=98288669&CFTOKEN=12911537
Mendeley's current release can't do this, would someone confirm: [link](http://feedback.mendeley.com/forums/4941-mendeley-feedback/suggestions/834313-version-0-9-7-does-not-extract-references-from-the)

> Hello - This feature was removed in
>   0.9.7 because it was consuming a fair amount of resources (client and server
>   side) without providing enough value.
>   We plan to re-introduce it in an
>   improved form in future

Comment: Seeing this problem with a bit of perspective, an idea would be to embed bibliographic metadata in PDF files. Maybe biblatex can do that or can be made to?

Comment: Cf. [Convert bibliographic references from a document into bibtex or endnote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781672/convert-bibliographic-references-from-a-document-into-bibtex-or-endnote/1833431#1833431), on SO.

Comment: @Damien: You can use the `hyperref` package to add DOI hyperlinks to the bibliography entries in your PDF files. Almost all papers have DOIs nowadays, and they uniquely identify the paper; no need to add anything else.

Comment: @Jukka well sure, but adding the DOI with bibtex does not make it easily extractible from the PDF…

Comment: @Damien: Why not? I'm referring to PDF *hyperlinks* that point to a URL of the form `http://dx.doi.org/something`; it should be very easy to extract all such hyperlinks from a PDF file.

Comment: Has anyone tried CrossRef's `pdf-extract` [tools](http://labs.crossref.org/styled-6/pdf_extract.html)? Seems like it might offer an answer to this question.

Comment: I have been looking this for years. It would be one of the most useful features for avoiding wasting time. There is no available software that actually can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try [cb2bib](http://www.molspaces.com/cb2bib/).

Comment: tried it...uses pdf2text from externtools/xpdf..its very incorrect in the output it generates